# Is there way to show pages with transparent background using Navigator 2.0 api in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigator, flutter-navigation

I'm trying to get full control on routes using Navigator 2.0 api. I want some pages to have transparent background (e.g. dialogs and bottom sheets) but still be represented as pages in Navigator. Naive way - just add a MaterialPage with partially transparent widget - doesn't work, lower page becomes black after transition animation.

Minimal code for reproduction is below. I expect to see red square (UpperPage) on green background (RootPage) but background becomes black. Navigator 1.0 api, like showGeneralDialog, works fine with this case, but I don't want to mix declarative and imperative way since it's hard to control from single source of truth like bloc or Provider. Is there any way to achieve this behaviour with pages api only?

```
class RootPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const RootPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox.expand(
      child: Container(color: Colors.green),
    );
  }
}

class UpperPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const UpperPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AppRouterDelegate extends RouterDelegate<String> with ChangeNotifier {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator(
      pages: const [
        MaterialPage(child: RootPage()),
        MaterialPage(child: UpperPage()),
      ],
      onPopPage: (route, result) {
        return route.didPop(result);
      },
    );
  }
...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TutorialOverlay extends ModalRoute<void> {
  @override
  Duration get transitionDuration => Duration(milliseconds: 500);

  @override
  bool get opaque => false;

  @override
  bool get barrierDismissible => false;

  @override
  Color get barrierColor => Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5);

  @override
  String get barrierLabel => null;

  @override
  bool get maintainState => true;

  @override
  Widget buildPage(
      BuildContext context,
      Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
      ) {
    // This makes sure that text and other content follows the material style
    return Material(
      type: MaterialType.transparency,
      // make sure that the overlay content is not cut off
      child: SafeArea(
        child: _buildOverlayContent(context),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildOverlayContent(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'This is a nice overlay',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30.0),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            child: Text('Dismiss'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildTransitions(
      BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
    // You can add your own animations for the overlay content
    return FadeTransition(
      opacity: animation,
      child: ScaleTransition(
        scale: animation,
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }
}


// Example application:
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Playground',
      home: TestPage(),
    );
  }
}

class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  void _showOverlay(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(TutorialOverlay());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Test')),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () => _showOverlay(context),
            child: Text('Show Overlay'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```